# How to do you add Mods to my Minecraft Bukkit Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

The Mod I want to install is [BuildCraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/286417-181-buildcraft-220-pipes-quarry-auto-crafting-building-engines/), so I am wondering how are you supposed to install Mods like that into a Bukkit Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular mod was designed for vanilla, offline Minecraft, so you aren't able to install it onto a Bukkit Server. However, had it been a Bukkit-compatible mod, you would download the files of the mod. Sometimes, you are provided with only a `.jar` file (ex. `SomeBukkitMod.jar`) – other times you are given a `.zip` containing a `.jar` and also a directory with the name of the mod containing preference files. Whichever you're given, put the files in the `/plugins` directory of your Bukkit Server.

Despite this, it seems a Minecraft Forums user by the name of *krnlyng* has [ported a few vanilla Minecraft server mods](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/382599-173-modloadermp-for-craftbukkit-and-canary/) over to Bukkit, including BuildCraft. This thread is linked to from the official BuildCraft thread so I'm assuming it's reliable; at the time of writing, though, it's only compatible with 1.7.3.